# Linux equivalent of the DOS "start" command?

Tags: windows, linux, scripting

I'm writing a ksh script and I have to run a executable at a separate Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you mean something like `xterm -e your.sh &`

Don't forget the final `&`

Comment: In windows I can do `start abcd.pdf` that opens the pdf file in the registered viewer. Is there anything similar in Linux?

Comment: @Jus12: `xdg-open abcd.pdf`

Comment: Just to add the importance of the final `&`, in python it does not execute the next line of code without it. So if you are automating, that `&` right there is the most important thing, if you want to wait until it ends, not put it there, but if you do not want to wait put it there, that is what I observed, @vartec highlighted, very important part.

Answer (score 27):

`xdg-open` is a similar command line app in linux.

see https://superuser.com/questions/38984/linux-equivalent-command-for-open-command-on-mac-windows for details on its use.

Answer (score 16):

maybe it´s not a seperate window that gets started, but you can run some executables in background using "&"

e.g.

```
./myexecutable &
```

means your script will not wait until myexecutable has finished but goes on immediately. maybe this is what you are looking for.
regards

Answer (score 8):

xdg-open is a good equivalent for the MS windows commandline start command:
    xdg-open file 
opens that file or url with its default application
    xdg-open .
opens the currect folder in the default file manager

Answer (score 4):

One of the most useful terminal session programs is screen.

```
screen -dmS title executable
```

You can list all your screen sessions by running

```
screen -ls
```

And you can connect to your created screen session (also allowing multiple simultaneous/synchronized sessions) by running

```
screen -x title
```

This will open up the emulated terminal in the current window where `executable` is running. You can detach a screen session by pressing C-a C-d, and can reattach as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want your program started in a new terminal window, you could do something like this:
xterm yourtextmodeprogram
or
gnome-terminal -e yourtextmodeprogram
or
konsole -e mc

Trouble is that you cannot count on a particular terminal emulator being installed, so (again: if you *really* want to do this) you would need to look for the common ones and then execute the first one encountered.

As Joachim mentioned: The normal way to do this is to background the command (read about shell job control somewhere, if you want to dig deeper).

There are also cases where you want to start a persistent shell, i.e. a shell session which lives on when you close the terminal window. There are two ways to do this:

- batch-oriented: nohup command-to-run &
- interactive:    screen

Answer (score 2):

if you want a new windows, just start a new instance of your terminal application: in kde it's

```
konsole -e whatever
```

i'm sure the Gnome terminal has similar options

Answer (score 2):

Some have recommended starting it in the background with &, but beware that that will still send all console output from the application you launch to the terminal you launched it from. Additionally, if you close the initial terminal the program you loaded will end.

If you're using a desktop environment like KDE or GNOME, I'd check the alt+f2 launching apps (gnome-open is the one for GNOME, I don't know the name of the KDE app) and see if you can pass them the command to launch as an argument.

Also, if your intention is to launch a daemon, you should check the [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I used `nohup` as the following command and it works:

`nohup <your command> &`

then press enter and enter!
don't forget the last `&`

for example, I ran a python code listening to port 5000:
`nohup python3 -W ignore mycode.py &`
then I made sure of running by `netstat -tulnp | grep :5000` and it was ok.