# Conditionally run process in background with bash

Tags: bash, sh

I would like to run a program conditionally in the background, if the condition is met, we run it as a daemon, otherwise we wait for the result:

```
if [ -z "${CONDITION}" ]; then
    echo "background" && npm install -g yarn &
else
    echo "foreground" && npm install -g yarn
fi
```

*is there a shorthand way to do this?* (I assume in the else block, that given the syntax that this process will not run in the background). I guess we could also conditionally add "wait" instead of an "&" character.

Comment: your `wait` idea seems good to me. Always start in backgound and do something like `[ -n "$CONDITION" ] && wait` ?  Don't know any other shorthand

Comment: do you mind adding your best version of that solution?

Comment: What makes you think that you can conditionally add a `wait` instead of an `&` ?

Comment: Look at the one answer we have, but youre right I mispoke..I meant use wait instead of the else block

Comment: Actually I didnt mispeak, LOL, if you switch the if/else we conditionally add the & character :)

Comment: Windows has a 'start' command which you can prefix with '$START cmd', to conditionally launch in background. For Linux see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591667/linux-equivalent-of-the-dos-start-command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your `wait` idea is good. I can't think of a better way.

```
npm install -g yarn &
[ -n "$CONDITION" ] && { echo "waiting for install"; wait; }
```

Not sure that you want the `echo` stuff or not, but if it's time consuming, you might want an indication.

HTH

Update: Simple script to show how it works

```
C=""
date
sleep 5s &
[ -n "$C" ] && { echo "waiting"; wait; }
date
```

If `C=""`, you get an output like so:

```
Thu Dec  8 11:42:54 CET 2016
Thu Dec  8 11:42:54 CET 2016
```

(and of course, `sleep 5s` is still running while your script is finished)

If you set `C="something"`, you get:

```
Thu Dec  8 11:42:42 CET 2016
waiting
Thu Dec  8 11:42:47 CET 2016
```

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen those {} brackets, maybe that's sytantically valid and groups the echo and the wait, but I guess you could also just do [ -n "$CONDITION" ] && echo "waiting for install" && wait;  right?

Comment: I am not sure if daemon's work like that, I will test it and see if this works! thanks

Comment: the brackets do work that way. They define kind of a block and in that case you need the semi colons. I am not sure what you mean by your second comment.  I will update my answer with a simple proof of concept.

Comment: `wait` with no arguments will wait for *all* background tasks to complete, which may not be what you want if this is part of a longer script that might start mulitiple tasks in the background. It would be slightly safer to run `wait $!` to wait for just the most recently started background task, or (safer yet) store the pid of the task in a variable (`npm_pid=$!`) and then use that (`wait $npm_pid`).